# How to check if a string contains a word and ignore special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to check if a sentence contains any of the word from a string array but while checking it should ignore special characters like comma. But the result should have original sentence.

For example, I have a sentence `"Tesla car price is $ 250,000."`
In my word array I've `wrdList = new string[5]{ "250000", "Apple", "40.00"};`

I have written the below line of code, but it is not returning the result because 250,000 and 250000 are not matching.

```
List<string> res = row.ItemArray.Where(itmArr => wrdList.Any(wrd => itmArr.ToString().ToLower().Contains(wrd.ToString()))).OfType<string>().ToList();
```

And one important thing is, I need to get original sentence if it matches with string array.

For example, result should be  `"Tesla car price is $ 250,000."`
not like `"Tesla car price is $ 250000."`

Comment: Can't you simply split the string and `TryParse` it and do the check on the numerical number ?

Comment: `.ToString().ToLower()` -> `.ToString().ToLower().Replace(",", "")`?

Comment: I doubt you need all of those `ToString`s if the types are already `string`

Comment: And if your array of words can contain characters it seems like you'd want to do `ToLower()` on `wrd` as well.

Comment: Your requirements could use some clarification. Will the words in your word list always be numeric? If not, what constitutes a "special character" that should be ignored? Is it only comma or are there others?

Comment: @JackA. Not always numeric, mix of Alpha and numeric. Special characters can be punctuation.

Comment: Special characters can't be "any". That implies any character is a special character. Do you mean any punctuation?

Answer (score 1):

How about `Replace(",", "")`

```
itmArr.ToString().ToLower().Replace(",", "").Contains(wrd.ToString())
```

side note: `.ToLower()` isn't required since digits are case insensitive and a string doesn't need `.ToString()`

so the resuld could also be

```
itmArr.Replace(",", "").Contains(wrd)
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/A2zN0d

---

**Update**
sice the `,` could be a different character - culture based, you can also use
`ystem.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator`
instead

Comment: but this will fail with different culture for example the ones that use ' instead of ,  "250'000"

Comment: the question was about comma:  _it should ignore special character comma._

Comment: @fubo - Sorry, I missed to add one point in my question. I've updated the question now.

Comment: @fubo actually the question is `How to check if a string contains a word and ignore special characters?`

Comment: @StefanoCavion what's wrong? https://dotnetfiddle.net/A2zN0d

Comment: @fubo OP ask to ignore special chars like comma not only comma so your solution , even if it's perfectly working for comma, is not generalized enough i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The first option to consider for most text matching problems is to use regular expressions. This will work for your problem. The core part of the solution is to construct an appropriate regular expression to match what you need to match.

You have a list of words, but I'll focus on just one word. Your requirements specify that you want to match on a "word". So to start with, you can use the "word boundary" pattern `\b`. To match the word "250000", the regular expression would be `\b250000\b`.

Your requirements also specify that the word can "contain" characters that are "special". For it to work correctly, you need to be clear what it means to "contain" and which characters are "special".

For the "contain" requirement, I'll assume you mean that the special character can be between any two characters in the word, but not the first or last character. So for the word "250000", any of the question marks in this string could be a special character: "2?5?0?0?0?0".

For the "special" requirement, there are options that depend on your requirements. If it's simply punctuation, you can use the character class `\p{P}`. If you need to specify a specific list of special characters, you can use a character group. For example, if your only special character is comma, the character group would be `[,]`.

To put all that together, you would create a function to build the appropriate regular expression for each target word, then use that to check your sentence. Something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string sentence = "Tesla car price is $ 250,000.";
    var targetWords = new string[]{ "250000", "350000", "400000"};
    Console.WriteLine($"Contains target word? {ContainsTarget(sentence, targetWords)}");
}

private static bool ContainsTarget(string sentence, string[] targetWords)
{
    return targetWords.Any(targetWord => ContainsTarget(sentence, targetWord));
}

private static bool ContainsTarget(string sentence, string targetWord)
{
    string targetWordExpression = TargetWordExpression(targetWord);
    var re = new Regex(targetWordExpression);
    return re.IsMatch(sentence);
}

private static string TargetWordExpression(string targetWord)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // If special characters means a specific list, use this:
    string specialCharacterMatch = $"[,]?";
    // If special characters means any punctuation, then you can use this:
    //string specialCharactersMatch = "\\p{P}?";
    
    bool any = false;
    foreach (char c in targetWord)
    {
        if (any)
        {
            sb.Append(specialCharacterMatch);
        }
        any = true;
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    
    return $"\\b{sb}\\b";
}
```

Working code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5UJSur

Answer (score -1):

Hope below solution can help,

- Used Regular expression for removing non alphanumeric characters
- Returns the original string if it contains any matching word from wrdList.

  ```
   string s = "Tesla car price is $ 250,000.";
       string[] wrdList = new string[3] { "250000", "Apple", "40.00" };

       Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
       string str = rgx.Replace(s, "");

       if (wrdList.Any(str.Contains))
       {
           Console.Write(s);
       }
       else
       {
           Console.Write("No Match Found!");
       }
  ```

Uplodade on fiddle for more exploration
https://dotnetfiddle.net/zbwuDy

In addition for paragraph, can split into array of sentences and iterate through. Check the same on below fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/AvO6FJ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).